# Ansible not using the 'group_vars' when playbook run

Tags: variables, ansible, ansible-inventory

Have a playbook that needs to connect to different test environments (`test1/5`, `test2/6`, `test3/7`, etc).

Each test has 3 nodes ea. Each environment has a different user ID to connect with (`test1-xabct1pc`, `test5-xabct5pc`, etc)

`/etc/ansible/hosts` is set up as:

```yaml
---
all:
  children:
    Test1:
      lab10[c:e]a.test.net
    Test2:
      lab10[f:h]a.test.net
    Test5:
      lab10[c:e]a.test.net
    Test6:
      lab10[f:h]a.test.net
... etc.
```

Under `/etc/ansible/group_vars/` I have `.yml` files that contain:

```yaml
---
ansible_user: xabct#pc

#- for whatever particular environment required.
```

Question is, why when I run the playback for `test2` it is picking up `test6` user ID?

Where in the hosts file or on the play book might I be able to declare this properly in order to get the expected results?

Am new to Ansible and it frustrates me.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to be working now. I can run the playback for a test env now. Is there any way to be able to run this for multiple test environments or all at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"Why when I run the playbook for `Test2` it is picking up the `Test6` user ID?"***

A: The hosts in group *Test2* are also members of group *Test6*. Ansible reads the files from the directory *group_vars* in alphabetical order (Test2.yml, Test6.yml). This is the reason that the variables from *Test6.yml* override previous declarations.

---

You have to run a playbook with a single group if you create the inventory like this. In this case, you either write a playbook for each particular group or a playbook that can be reused by multiple groups.

1. If you create special playbooks for each group put the variable *ansible_user* into the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: Test2
  vars:
    ansible_user: 2pc
  ...
```

2. Declare the below variables in *groups_vars/all.yml* if you want to reuse a playbook for multiple groups

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all.yml
id:
  Test1: 1pc
  Test2: 2pc
  Test3: 3pc
  Test4: 4pc
  Test5: 5pc
  Test6: 6pc
ansible_user: "{{ id[my_group] }}"
```

Then, use the variable *my_group* for both to specify the *hosts* and select *ansible_user*. For example, the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
all:
  children:
    Test2:
      hosts:
        l[f:h]:
    Test6:
      hosts:
        l[f:h]:
```

and the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ my_group }}"
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_user
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e my_group=Test2

PLAY [Test2] ************************************************

TASK [debug] ***********************************************
ok: [lf] => 
  ansible_user: 2pc
ok: [lg] => 
  ansible_user: 2pc
ok: [lh] => 
  ansible_user: 2pc
```

Comment: Thank you Vladir, this works for the individual  'test' environment.  In my hosts file I have a TESTALL:  that has children Test2 & Test6.  How can I se this up in the group _vars so I can  run a playbook against the TESTALL and have it  run against Test2 & Test6 ?

Comment: The hosts of the groups *Test2* and *Test6* are identical. Now your question can be rephrased: *`What group does such a host belong to?`*